# Line height Behaving differently for few elements in IE with same set of rule

Tags: html, css

I'm facing alignment issues wrt `line-height` in IE versions. I have given line-height and  height as 14 px to `span` tag to make the text vertically center. It's working fine for all LI elements in UL. But for last 3 li elements in my list the same line height pushing content little uppish. For last 3 items in UL list, 15px line height is working to make text center align.

How come same CSS rule behaves differently for few items in the list

**HTML**

```
    <ul>
      <li>   <span class="line"> Text </span></li>
      <li>   <span class="line"> Text </span></li>
      <li>   <span class="line"> Text </span></li>
      ....
      ....
      ....
      <li>   <span class="line"> Text </span></li>
      <li>   <span class="line"> Text </span></li>
      <li>   <span class="line"> Text </span></li>
    </ul>
```

**Css**

```
.line {
    background-color: #e55c17;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    font: bold 11px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
    padding: 1px 3px;   
    margin-top: 1px;
    line-height: 14px;
    height: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Why have you two * in you codes?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.. updated now

Comment: I put your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/gL0L7a4j/), but I don't really see the issue. Could you edit the fiddle so that it properly demonstrates the problem?